# copy all files and directory of the folder tar it and then send it destination for untar in python

Tags: python

I need to copy all files and directory of folder with same permission after tarring it, send it to the target host (via sftp) then untar it to the same location.

I am new to python and just curious to do it via python script.

Comment: Looks like you want somebody else to write some code for you for free. Do you have any specific question?

Comment: i don't want that somebody writes code for me, fyi.. stackoverflow is free platform ,and i am looking for hint, i can write this in shell script.

Comment: Just to clarify: this question seems to override [What kind of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)'s tips. I suggest you to edit the question to be [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @SebasSBM.where you find this is override? and What's wrong here?

Comment: You should include what you tried so far. Even through it is a specific question, it looks too vague. As @timgeb said, it looks like you want someone to make code for you for free. Sharing what documentation have you read to try to solve the problem would show some effort by your side. I reccommend you to take a look at [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, the title is way too large. and basically the question itself is like a duplicate of the title with one or two extra details. Try to make the title shorter, the details can be provided in the question's content.

Comment: But most important thing of all: questions asking for tutorials are off-topic in this site, as explained in [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the python standard modules! Tar and zip files are easy with python.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html

Comment: Ending every sentence with an exclamation mark! Makes you sound overexcited! Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731 and either edit or delete this answer accordingly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe your forgot to end your last sentence with a !

Comment: You are right, but i was not overexcited, just amazed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "Ending every sentence with an exclamation mark" is not a sentence; it is a sentence fragment.

Comment: @zondo I know, but I wanted to fit in more than one. Ending every sentence fragment with an exclamation mark also makes you sound overexcited, though, so I didn't feel it detracted from the purpose of the exercise.